# How do I make a timer that changes how many ticks he runs on different occasions?

Tags: c#, timer

I'm trying to code a Simon Says game and I ran into a problem. I cannot figure out how to make my Randomizer timer (that randomizes which boxes are lit up) to run by waves. I want it to run once, then when it's referred to again - run twice and so on.

This is RandomPlace():

```
private PictureBox RandomPlace()
    {
        PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        switch (rnd.Next(1, 5))
        {
            case 1:
                p = TopRight;
                break;
            case 2:
                p = TopLeft;
                break;
            case 3:
                p = BottomRight;
                break;
            case 4:
                p = BottomLeft;
                break;
        }
        return p; 
    } //Gets a random PictureBox
```

This is RandomImage():

```
private void RandomImage()
    {
        TopLeft.Enabled = false;
        TopRight.Enabled = false;
        BottomLeft.Enabled = false;
        BottomRight.Enabled = false;


        PictureBox a = RandomPlace();
        if (a == TopLeft)
        {
            TopLeft.Image = Resources.TopLeftLit;
            label1.Text = "TopLeft"; 
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            TopLeft.Image = Resources.TopLeft;
            label2.Text = "TopLeftAFTERSLEEP";
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            pattern[patternRightNow] = 1;
            patternRightNow++;
        }

        if (a == TopRight)
        {
            TopRight.Image = Resources.TopRightLit;
            label1.Text = "TopRight";
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            TopRight.Image = Resources.TopRight;
            label2.Text = "TopRightAFTERSLEEP";    //FIGURE OUT HOW TO RESET PICTURE
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            pattern[patternRightNow] = 2;
            patternRightNow++;
        }

        if (a == BottomLeft)
        {
            this.BottomLeft.Image = Resources.BottomLeftLit;
            label1.Text = "BottomLeft";
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            this.BottomLeft.Image = Resources.BottomLeft;
            label2.Text = "BottomLeftAFTERSLEEP";
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            pattern[patternRightNow] = 3;
            patternRightNow++;
        }

        if (a == BottomRight)
        {
            this.BottomRight.Image = Resources.BottomRightLit;
            label1.Text = "BottomRight";
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            this.BottomRight.Image = Resources.BottomRight;
            label2.Text = "BottomRightAFTERSLEEP";
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            pattern[patternRightNow] = 4;
            patternRightNow++;
        }
    } //Lits up the random PictureBoxes and sets them back to normal
```

This is Randomizer_Tick():

```
rivate void Randomizer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RandomImage();
        patternRightNow = 0; 
        tickCount++;
        Randomizer.Stop();
        ClickCheck();
    } //Use RandomImage() to lit up random PictureBoxes on 5 waves, wave 1 - 1 PictureBox, wave 2 - 2 PictureBoxes and so on.
```

This is ClickCheck():

```
private void ClickCheck()
    {
        TopLeft.Enabled = true;
        TopRight.Enabled = true;
        BottomLeft.Enabled = true;
        BottomRight.Enabled = true;

        if (tickCount == clickCount)
        {
            CheckIfWin();
            Randomizer.Start();
        }
    } //Enables the PictureBoxes to be pressed, after the user input reaches the current wave's amount of PictureBoxes lit up, disable PictureBoxes again and start the randomizer
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using timers, I advise you to look at Tasks. It's much easier to create such statemachines.

Fill a list with colors and play it. Wait until the user pressed enough buttons and check the results.

For example: (haven't tested it, it's just for example/pseudo code)
It might contain some typo's.

```
private List<int> _sequence = new List<int>();
private List<int> _userInput = new List<int>();
private Random _rnd = new Random(DataTime.UtcNow.Milliseconds);
private bool _running = true;
private bool _inputEnabled = false;
private TaskCompletionSource<object> _userInputReady;

public async void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(_running)
        return;
        
    while(_running)
    {
        // add a color/button
        _sequence.Add(_rnd.Next(4));

        // play the sequence
        for(int color in _sequence)
        {
            // light-up your image, whatever
            Console.WriteLine(color);
            // wait here...
            await Task.Delay(300);
            // turn-off your image, whatever
        }

        // clear userinput
        _userInput.Clear();
        _userInputReady = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        _inputEnabled = true;

        // wait for user input.
        await _userInputReady.Task;
        
        // compare the user input to the sequence.
        
        for(int i=0;i<_sequence.Count;i++)
        {
            if(_sequence[i] != _userInput[i])
            {
            
                _running = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Not correct");
}

// one handler for all buttons. Use the .Tag property to store 0, 1, 2, 3
public void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!_inputEnabled)
        return;
        
    var button = (Button)sender;
    
    // add user input to the queue
    _userInput.Add((int)button.Tag);
    
    if(_userInput.Count >= _sequence.Count)
        _userInputReady.SetResult(null);
}
```

Comment: I have to use timers because that is the subject we're learning in my class right now, is there any way to do it with a timer?